# Strange behaviour filtering Swift Array by Type

Tags: swift, swift2

Can someone explain to me why the following code seems to fail to differentiate between numeric types?

```
extension Array {
    func filterByType<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var r = [T]()
        for case let m as T in self {
            r += [m]
        }
        return r
    }
    func filterByType2<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var r = [T]()
        for m in self {
            if m is T {
                r += [m as! T]
            }
        }
        return r
    }
}

let objects = [1, "2", 3, "4", 5.1, [1, 2]]

typealias IntArray = [Int]

objects.filterByType(String.self) // ["2", "4"] - as expected
objects.filterByType(IntArray.self) // [[1, 2]] - as expected
objects.filterByType(Double.self) // [1, 3, 5.1] - ok, but surprised 1 & 3 aren't Ints
objects.filterByType(Int.self) // [1, 3, 5] - why?

objects.filterByType2(String.self) // ["2", "4"] - as expected
objects.filterByType2(IntArray.self) // [[1, 2]] - as expected
objects.filterByType2(Double.self) // [1, 3, 5.1] - ok, but surprised 1 & 3 aren't Ints
objects.filterByType2(Int.self) // [1, 3, 5] - why?
```

Comment: Could you try this with `let objects : [Any] = ...`? I got the results that you expect that way, but I have an earlier Xcode installed.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You are right, that gives the "expected" results also with Xcode 7 beta 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any type annotation, the type of the heterogenous array

```
let objects = [1, "2", 3, "4", 5.1, [1, 2]]
```

is inferred as `[NSObject]`. In particular, the numbers are converted
to `NSNumber` objects. A (conditional) cast from `NSNumber` to `Double`
or `Int` always succeeds and uses the `doubleValue` or `integerValue`
method.

This can be seen with the following simple example:

```
let n1 = NSNumber(integer: 123)
if let x = n1 as? Double { // warning: conditional cast from 'NSNumber' to 'Double' always succeeds
    print(x) // 123.0
}

let n2 = NSNumber(double: 12.8)
if let x = n2 as? Int { // warning: conditional cast from 'NSNumber' to 'Double' always succeeds
    print(x) // 12
}
```

See also

- the "Numbers" section in ["Working with Cocoa Data Types"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation,
- the "Value Conversions" section in the [`NSNumber` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html).

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The objects array is inferred to be of type `NSObject` and the numbers are of type `NSNumber` which can be casted to `Int`, `Double` and even `Bool` (probably unexpected).

So in order to get the desired behavior you should explicitly declare the type of your array as `[Any]`

As improvement for your algorithm I would suggest to use `flatMap`:

```
extension Array {
    func filterByType<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return self.flatMap{ $0 as? T }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following two lines in `filterByType` and `filterByType2` are casting the `Int` and `Double` values. The `String` and `[Int]` types give the expected results because these cannot be cast.

```
for case let m as T in self {
// ...
r += [m as! T]
```

1, 3, 5.1 can be cast as `Double` or `Int`.